# How to Expand Sidebar on Wordpress Dashboard

Tags: wordpress, sidebar

I accidentally (not sure how) collapsed the sidebar on my Wordpress dashboard, so now all I can see are icons instead of "Media", "Plugins", etc. I can't get it to re-expand, and search results are only showing how to create a Wordpress sidebar, not how to manipulate the existing dashboard sidebar. I'm sure the answer is very simple, but does anyone know how to make it re-expand?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The very bottom icon is to expand/collapse the panel. [image] [image]

Comment: Ah, thank you! I didn't realize I could scroll the sidebar down, that icon was hidden on my view.